# How to affect the column order with Entity Framework Code First Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.3

I'm using Entity Framework 4.3 Code First and trying out the Migrations feature.

If I add a new property to my class and then run Add-Migration from the package manager console window I get something like this:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("Products", "Discontinued", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
    }
```

I would like to be able to affect the order of the column as I don't want it to just be appended to the table but rather placed at a specific index. I thought I might be able to add it to my modelBuilder configuration, something like:

```
Property(p => p.Discontinued).HasColumnOrder(2);
```

but running Update-database does not appear to use it. Can this be done as a migration?

Comment: a) There is no way to insert into previous columns without doing a lot of hacking, b) you shouldn't be keeping deprecated data in your database by using "soft-deletes" - look into archiving deprecated data.

Comment: What is the point of having columns in database table in specific order? It is just a data storage.

Comment: Just for aesthetic purposes, that's all. You can specify it when the database is created with the model builder so just wondered if it's possible when adding a new column as part of a migration. No big deal.

Comment: For me, this is a huge issue.  I'm setting up a Code First model to match an existing (huge) database. The CF tools don't allow you to enforce an order on the newly-built database, and the Schema Compare tool does not appear to allow you to ignore column order.  With hundreds of tables, it will take me days instead of hours.

Answer (score 6):

This is just a matter of missing functionality. SQL by itself does not rely on any implicit order of columns (with some exceptions: ORDER BY , ...).

Neither SQL Server nor ORACLE do have a direct SQL DDL command (aka `ALTER TABLE...`) to move a column around.

Therefore there's no possibility to change the order without high effort (recreate the table). See for example

- [How To change the column order of An Existing Table in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781151/how-to-change-the-column-order-of-an-existing-table-in-sql-server-2008)
- [SQL SERVER – Change Order of Column In Database Tables](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/08/sql-server-change-order-of-column-in-database-tables/)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61978/how-to-change-the-column-order